# Firebase Cloud Storage - upload with metadata -

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I wish to upload files from the browser with metadata that will allow the files to be identified and handled correctly with cloud functions.

On the client my uploader code looks like this:

```
    uploadTaskPromise: async function (file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {      
        const storageRef = storage.ref();
        const myRef = storageRef.child(`myfolder/${my_file_name}.wav`);
        const metadata = {
          project_id: my_project_id
        };
       
        const uploadTask = myRef.put(file, { metadata: metadata });    
        uploadTask.on("state_changed",(snapshot) => {
          const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");            
         },   
         function error(err) {
           console.log("error", err);
           reject();
          }, 
          function complete() {
          uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
          .then(function (downloadURL) {
             resolve(downloadURL);
           });
         }    
       )
     });
   },
```

And on the server (Firebase Cloud Functions using Node js)

```
exports.uploadHandler = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => { 
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
  const metadata = await bucket.file(object.name).getMetadata()
  console.log("METADATA: " + JSON.stringify(metadata))
 
  // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO HANDLE UPLOADS BASED ON THE METADATA
  
  return ({ message: "file uploaded" })
});
```

The `uploadHandler` is working - but `metadata` is `undefined`, as is `metadata.metadata`

How can I access the metadata that I uploaded from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close. As per the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.Reference#put), the second argument is an [`UploadMetadata` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.UploadMetadata) which has a property called [`customMetadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.UploadMetadata#optional-custommetadata).

So, to correct your code, you'd swap out

```js
myRef.put(file, { metadata: metadata });
```

with

```js
wmyRef.put(file, { customMetadata: metadata });
```

Additionally, your progress logic shouldn't call `resolve` and `reject` like it is at the moment - that's [an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743). You should instead chain to `UploadTask`'s own Promise API.

```js
return wmyRef.put(file, { customMetadata: metadata })
  .then(
    (snapshot) => { // onComplete
      return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    },
    (err) => { // onError (although I would just omit this entirely)
      console.log("failed to upload", err);
      throw err;
    }
  );
```

With your original code, if `getDownloadURL()` failed, its error wouldn't be handled.

If you still want progress reporting, use:

```js
const uploadTask = wmyRef.put(file, { customMetadata: metadata });

uploadTask.on(
  "state_changed",
  (snapshot) => {
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");            
  }
);

return uploadTask
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log("Upload is complete");
    return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
  });
```

Comment: Yep that totally worked - thank you.  I had edited my code for brevity before posting - hence the antipattern that you correctly identified.  In case anyone else comes across this question I have corrected the code to its original (working) state- thanks again.

Comment: @AlexWebster See update for handling progress changes without encountering the antipattern.